# xPath of element when HTML is identical

Tags: html, xpath, nested

I have this mark up:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="text">Bedford, Franklin Court</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
    <td> 
            <span> First Row</span> 
    </td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="text">Jo Ghartey_Officer4)</span>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="text">Jo Ghartey_Oficer4)</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to find the xpath of the FIRST span which contains Jo Ghartey. I've tried using following sibling after the span containing 'Bedford' however I can't always guarantee that the `<tr> <td> <span>`will always be the second `<tr>` after the Bedoford `<tr>`. So when I try `xpath=//span[contains(,.'Bedford')]/../../following-sibling::tr[2]/td/span` it finds the element no problem. But if there is another `<tr> <td> <span>` between Bedford and Jo Ghartey, then I will have to change the index. What I do know is that I will always be looking for the first span containing Jo Ghartey. I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `(//span[contains(., 'Jo Ghartey')])[1]` you select the first `span` element whose string values contains the string `Jo Ghartey`.

Comment: The OP may need to adopt this to find the desired `following-sibling` so looking for the first following-sibling `<span>` with attribute `class` = "text" might be closer to what the OP was looking for. +1 nonetheless.